# Why SVN doesn't commit my external library?

Tags: java, svn, java-3d

I know this question has already ask many times in other context, but I can't find a solution.

Why SVN doesn't commit my external library?

First, I'm working with a team and we don't want to add my external library each time we import the project from SVN. We don't work on the same computer each times.

Second, the library that I created contain the link (I add externals JAR) for j3dcore, j3dutils and vecmath that I put in a folder in my project. Also I set the native location to the bin folder (of java 3D) that I also put in my project.
With that, we don't have to install Java 3D each time we use a new computer. It works very well, but the problems is there, SVN doesn't commit it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `svn add /path/to/library.jar`, and then `svn commit`.

Comment: what commands do you run, what is the output, what is the output you expect to see? this question is pretty much unanswerable in it's current state.

Comment: _each time we import the project from SVN_. People generally `export` from SVN (or `update` or `checkout`), as these are the commands that are used.

Comment: If I understand you, I guess you added that library as a dependency in the IDE, so there's some kind of link to the library, but the library isn't physically inside your project. If that's the case, the setting may be in an IDE preference file that's not being committed. I'd suggest you to start using Maven or similar for dependency management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the commit of subsclipse didn't commit the .classpath of the project (I don't know why). So the buildpath come wrong when we try to download our project on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the files to your repository before you `commit`.

You have not said what SVN client you are using, but if you are using the command line, do something like this:

```
$ svn add lib/j3dcore.jar
$ svn add lib/j3dutils.jar
$ svn add lib/vecmath .jar
$ svn commit -m "Added thirdparty JARs."
```